# Click an OK web button that has no value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting crazy to click a button on a webpage where the VBA always tells me Object required!

the button code is

```
<em 
class="" unselectable="on">
<button type="button" id="ext-gen47" 
class=" x-btn-text">OK</button>
</em>
```

I've tried

```
doc.getElementById("button").Click
```

But gets an error that an object is required!

Also tried

```
Dim myBtn As Object
    Set myBtn = doc.getElementsByClassName("x-btn-mc")(0)
    myBtn.Click
```

But nothing happens - I'm not sure what's wrong I'm doing or missing

My full code is

```
Sub testing()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

'Dim doc As InternetExplorerMedium'

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "www.example.com"  'I can't expose the webpage I'm working one'

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
Loop

Set elements = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
Set btns = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("td")


For Each element In elements

        If element.className = "x-tree-node-anchor" And element.tabIndex = "1" And element.innerText Like "Credit And Rebill" Then
            element.Click
        End If

    Next element
    Set doc = Nothing

Set doc = IE.document

doc.getElementById("credit_and_rebill_bill_id").Value = "0000000"
doc.getElementById("credit_and_rebill_reference_id").Value = "5678 ID"
doc.getElementById("credit_rebill_reason_code").Value = "CR - Regeneration"
'doc.getElementById("credit_rebill_reason_code").Value = "CR - Transfer"'

'Dim myBtn As Object'
    'Set myBtn = doc.getElementsByClassName("x-btn-mc")(0)'
    'myBtn.Click'


doc.getElementById("button").Click


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: 1. You should be using `IE` not `Doc` (as `Doc` is commented out!) 2. `doc.getElementById("button").Click` should be `IE.getElementByID("ext-gen47")`.

Comment: @SamuelEverson Thank you for the hint, I've also tried this before and always get an error saying (Run-time error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method. Which I still don't understand even after researching it!

Comment: That should've been `IE.Document....` but does it throw this error at any other line? (like the 2 get element methods above? And did you already try it by looping the elements (the same as earlier in your code) to find the button and click it?

Comment: I think you're probably better off starting from scratch with this tutorial since your code is incomplete and has several errors in it: https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s324/vba-ie.htm

Comment: @SamuelEverson  Yes I did try the loop option as in the for loop in my code and didn't help, it did loop but the button never being clicked. I had a look on the link provided, I also researched an answer over the internet but didn't reach anything! - it's very frustrating :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waiting for 1 second before clicking the OK button fixed the issue

```
'Waiting for 1 second to click the OK button'
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

'Clicking the OK button'
doc.getElementsByClassName("x-btn-mc")(0).Click
```